# Erro no meu flappy bird

Tags: javascript

No meu codigo as barreiras continuam do mesmo tamanho sem alternar quando passam.

O que pode ser?

```
function novoElemento(tagName, className) {
    const elem = document.createElement(tagName);
    elem.className = className;
    return elem;
}

function Barreira(reversa = false) {
    this.elemento = novoElemento('div', 'barreira');

    const borda = novoElemento('div', 'borda');
    const corpo = novoElemento('div', 'corpo');
    this.elemento.appendChild(reversa ? corpo : borda);
    this.elemento.appendChild(reversa ? borda : corpo);

    this.setAltura = altura => corpo.style.heigth = `${altura}px`;
}

// const b = new Barreira(true);
// b.setAltura(300);
// document.querySelector('[wm-flappy').appendChild(b.elemento);

function ParDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, x) {
    this.elemento = novoElemento('div', 'par-de-barreiras');

    this.superior = new Barreira(true);
    this.inferior = new Barreira(false);

    this.elemento.appendChild(this.superior.elemento);
    this.elemento.appendChild(this.inferior.elemento);

    this.sortearAbertura = () => {
        const alturaSuperior = Math.random() * (altura - abertura);
        const alturaInferior = altura - abertura - alturaSuperior;
        this.superior.setAltura(alturaSuperior);
        this.inferior.setAltura(alturaInferior);
    }

    this.getX = () => parseInt(this.elemento.style.left.split('px')[0]);
    this.setX = x => this.elemento.style.left = `${x}px`;
    this.getLargura = () => this.elemento.clientWidth;

    this.sortearAbertura();
    this.setX(x);
}

// const b = new ParDeBarreiras(700, 200, 800);
// document.querySelector('[wm-flappy]').appendChild(b.elemento);

function Barreiras(altura, largura, abertura, espaco, notificarPonto) {
    this.pares = [
        new ParDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, largura),
        new ParDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, largura + espaco),
        new ParDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, largura + espaco * 2),
        new ParDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, largura + espaco * 3)
    ]

    const deslocamento = 3;
    this.animar = () => {
        this.pares.forEach(par => {
            par.setX(par.getX() - deslocamento);

            // quando o elemento sair da área do jogo
            if (par.getX() < -par.getLargura()) {
                par.setX(par.getX() + espaco * this.pares.length);
                par.sortearAbertura()
            }

            const meio = largura / 2;
            const cruzouOMeio = par.getX() + deslocamento >= meio
                && par.getX() < meio;
            if (cruzouOMeio) notificarPonto();

        })
    }
}

const barreiras = new Barreiras(700, 1200, 200, 400);
const areaDoJogo = document.querySelector('[wm-flappy');
barreiras.pares.forEach(par => areaDoJogo.appendChild(par.elemento));
setInterval(() => {
    barreiras.animar();
}, 20)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estou tentando elaborar uma resposta, mas fica difícil entender o que você está montando sem informar um pouco mais sobre o seu HTML e sobre o seu CSS. Além disso, está faltando o `]` no seu `.querySelector('[wm-flappy')`.

Comment: Opa boa tarde e um jogo do flappy bird!!! Mas as barreiras estão ficando do mesmo tamanho sem variar e noa to conseguindo enxergar o erro nisso. Valeu vou arrumar

Comment: Eu sei que é um flappy bird. O que estou dizendo é que coisas como tamanho e posição dos elementos do HTML ficam difíceis de entender e de ver o que pode ter de errado neles sem ter a estrutura do HTML que você montou e nem o CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Barreira(reversa = false) {
    this.elemento = novoElemento('div', 'barreira');
```

no lugar de barreira "par-de-barreiras"

Answer (score 0):

this.setAltura = altura => corpo.style.heigth = `${altura}px`;

o heigth está escrito incorretamente

Comment: Seja bem vinda Elza, apenas uma dica: Agrupe suas respostas, evitando a duplicidade de respostas na mesma pergunta. Leie: [Duas respostas do mesmo autor na mesma pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6740/duas-respostas-do-mesmo-autor-na-mesma-pergunta)